# JavaScript, Reading and Writing files for a locally hosted application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read several posts on this site that ask similar questions but the key difference is they involve a client and a server. For my use, this is not the case. I am simply pasting a file directory on my computer into my browser in order to view a local HTML file, packed with CSS and some jQuery.

I've been looking around and the answers I've found are "No; a client can not write to a server", and "No; a server can not write to a client". But there is no answer to "can a client write to a client with JavaScript?"

Use case:
I'm building a webapp (website? JS app?) as a college project for a stock management tool that will be locally hosted and never connect to the internet. Sure, I could knock one together in python in a couple hours, but I wouldn't learn anything. I need to create an access a txt file containing an array of the current stock of all the items so that when the application is loaded, the user doesn't have to manually enter anything but the changes to stock levels.

Honestly, I'm a beginner at JS and JQ and I'm only going off of what makes sense based on a mix of HTML and Python that I know.
Maybe PHP would be the better option for this particular option, or maybe JS will work well enough.

Comment: The browser is limited to what it can do with the file system. Makes sense since do you want a person to be able to save stuff to your local drive. You can run a local node server and have node write to the file system. Also JavaScript when running off file:// is very limited and has some weird restrictions.

Comment: The only way to use hard drive files in a file:/// environment is to have the user select the file using `<input type="file">` to read it and trigger a download to have the user overwrite it to save it. There's no other way. You can however simply run a local server (use xampp for PHP, or node to use JS to write the server). It requires no internet connection but enables you to access the hard drive. Also, https://www.electronjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You still won't be doing client-to-client, your browser will just act as though the local file system is the server using the `file://` protocol which means the same rules about a "client" (the browser) cannot write to a "server" (your local file system) apply.

If you wan't to be able to write an application that can interface **directly** with the filesystem, then look into something like [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) which is essentially an augmented website that gives you APIs to interact with the actual computer the app is being run on, including filesystem stuff.